# Win32api Only accept int but float needed

Tags: python, winapi

Hi I have an issue here.
I have this code I made which is working:

```
nosum = int(round(startX * 0.9))
nosum2 = int(round(y * 0.5))
win32api.SetCursorPos((nosum,nosum2))

win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,nosum,nosum2,0,0)
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,nosum,nosum2,0,0)
```

The issue is that I had to make an int(round(var)) because win32api expects parametere to be int, but for my use I need the value to be float, How do I achieve this?

Comment: Use floats internally and round them to ints when you pass them to the API.

Comment: I need the api to use the floats, since I have to 'click' something that is not an integer but a float in this case.

Comment: That makes no sense.

Comment: These numbers are integers for a reason. You can either click on the 3rd or the 4th pixel, clicking on the 3.5th one doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Andomar Pixel number 3.5 was a ridiculous idea when the Win32 API was designed in the mid 90s, but more than 20 years later, who deals with physical pixels? You could be drawing to a virtual texture that gets fed to a 3D compositor or something, and your actual monitor that the compositor sees may have 1.67x higher resolution than what the windowing system reports, and so on. So, she may not be clueless, just expecting too much from an old API.

Comment: Unclear, why you are faking your input across discrete API calls. This should be a single call to [SendInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310.aspx). Passing the `MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE` flag through the [MOUSEINPUT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273.aspx) structure allows you to pass values with resolution higher than the physical screen resolution.

Answer (score 1):

The API function determines its interface. It accepts integer valued coordinates. This is a basic principle about an interface. The implementor decides on the rules and the consumer must follow them. You must pass integer values.

As for why integers are required, the `SetCursorPosition` function operates in screen pixels. These are discrete and indivisible. The system simply does not offer any means to describe the cursor position in terms of fractional coordinates.